# I have json array data which needs to be fetched in a foreach loop for capacitor and DG using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I want to fetch the below json data using php:

```
 $str ='{
  "site_Id": "1",
  "site_Name": "Guajarat",
  "site_Address": "Emami",
  "site_StartDate": "10 / November / 2017   To   11 / November / 2017",
  "Capacitor": [
  {
  "checkList_Id_PointNo": "1",
  "checkList_Name": "APFC Panel doors and covers properly closed",
  "checkList_Status": "Not OK",
  "checkList_Remark": "Remark 1",
  "checkList_Photo": "11Capacitor BankCapacitor Name1",
  "fk_equipmentType": "Capacitor Bank"    
  },
  {
  "checkList_Id_PointNo": "2",
  "checkList_Name": "APFC Panel door locks working properly.",
  "checkList_Status": "Not OK",
  "checkList_Remark": "Remark ",
  "checkList_Photo": "11Capacitor BankCapacitor Name2",
  "fk_equipmentType": "Capacitor Bank"
  }
  ],
 "DG": [
  {
  "checkList_Id_PointNo": "1",
  "checkList_Name": "Substation earthing layout clearly making the position or earthing pits with identification number and the route of earthing lead / strip",
  "checkList_Status": "Not OK",
  "checkList_Remark": "Remark gg",
  "checkList_Photo": "12EarthingDG Earthing1",
  "fk_equipmentType": "Earthing"
  },
  {
  "checkList_Id_PointNo": "2",
  "checkList_Name": "All earhting pits should have identification number as indicated in earthing layout written over them with permanent paint",
  "checkList_Status": "Not OK",
  "checkList_Remark": "Remark gg",
  "checkList_Photo": "12EarthingDG Earthing2",
  "fk_equipmentType": "Earthing"
  }
  ]
 }';
```

Until now i have only coded for the Capacitor but i also need to fetch both Capacitor and DG from the same loop. Below is the foreach loop from which i have only fetch data of Capacitor but in that loop i also need to fetch DG at the same time.

```
foreach ($json['Capacitor'] as $field => $value) {
    $id = $json['Capacitor'][$field]['checkList_Id_PointNo'];
    $name = $json['Capacitor'][$field]['checkList_Name'];
    $status = $json['Capacitor'][$field]['checkList_Status'];
    $remark = $json['Capacitor'][$field]['checkList_Remark'];
    $photo = $json['Capacitor'][$field]['checkList_Photo'];
    echo $id.'<br>'.$name.'<br>'.$status.'<br>'.$remark.'<br>'.$photo.'<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: this is the link:- https://eval.in/898471

Comment: @AlivetoDie : I have edited the question please check i have posted the correct format of json which i require. I am very sorry for the inconvenience please can you help me with it.

Comment: As i said you din't provided the correct input data. Don't do it in next future. Provide full input data

Comment: @AlivetoDie : Thanks for the solution and your time. I just need one more thing i need to insert capacitor & DG also into the database with each json object.

Comment: @AlivetoDie : $key is not printing capacitor and DG with each of its array. Please help. I want to echo "INSERT INTO table (type,id, name, status, remark, photo) VALUES ('?','$id', '$name', '$status','$remark','$photo')".PHP_EOL; in which the type should contain capacitor or DG for its particular array value.

Comment: Sorry it need to be like this:- https://eval.in/898572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$json = json_decode($str,true);
print_r($json);


foreach ($json as $value) {
  if(is_array($value)){
    foreach($value as $val){
       $id = $val['checkList_Id_PointNo'];
       $name = $val['checkList_Name'];
       $status = $val['checkList_Status'];
       $remark = $val['checkList_Remark'];
       $photo = $val['checkList_Photo'];
       echo "INSERT INTO table (id, name, status, remark, photo) VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$status','$remark','$photo')".PHP_EOL; // i have printed it so that you can see that it's printing perfectly.
    }
  }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/898497